# "I wish I didn't do" vs. "I wish I hadn't done"

Tags: word-choice, tenses, past-perfect, simple-past

> Now I feel sick. I wish I [didn't eat/hadn't eaten] pork with cheese for dinner.

I would use "hadn't eaten" as it was my dinner but "now I feel sick" confuses me.

Comment: Question has already been answered, but as an additional point "I wish I didn't do" would refer to something on going. "I wish I didn't eat so much" would mean you wish you ate less in general whereas "I wish I hadn't ate so much" would mean just now.

Comment: Contrary to what's been said in some of the answers and comments, the simple past doesn't necessarily indicate a habitual or ongoing action. In the context you present, it can refer to a single event happening in the past (in this case, *what you ate for dinner last night*, assuming you felt sick the next day).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are asking about matching tenses.

Firstly, notice that both sentences are correct but they have different meanings.

**1.**

> Now I feel sick. I wish I didn't eat pork with cheese for dinner.

This is an expression of regret for a commonly repeated action. You can replace it with:

*Now I feel sick. I wish I didn't habitually eat pork with cheese for dinner.*

**2.**

> Now I feel sick. I wish I hadn't eaten pork with cheese for dinner.

This is a regret for a one-off action, we could say, e.g.

*Now I feel sick. I wish I hadn't eaten pork with cheese for dinner last night.*

**Answer**

Now we come to the matter of matching tenses. Let's look at the following:

*Now I feel sick. I wish ***that*** I hadn't eaten pork with cheese for dinner last night.*

Notice that I have inserted the implied "that".

There is no conflict of tense. The tense structure is -

a. *now I feel sick* - present tense of 'to feel'

b. *now I wish (something)* - present tense of 'to wish'

c. *that I hadn't eaten* - subordinate clause, past perfect

Comment: You should probably include ***continuous*** as well as ***commonly repeated*** in your "first meaning" section. *I wish I didn't love you. Now I'm going to regret leaving you for a younger woman*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yes - I missed that one. Point taken. I'll leave my answer as is because I'm only dealing with the given example.

Answer (score 0):

Those are two separate sentences. There's no reason for the tenses in different sentences to agree. Consider:

> Yesterday it was cold. Today it is warmer. Tomorrow it will be cold again.

So yes, you want *hadn't*:

> Now I feel sick. I wish I hadn't eaten pork with cheese for dinner.

Comment: exactly, you "feel sick" now, but ate your dinner in the past

Answer (score 0):

The statements are grammatically correct but would not be spoken by a native speaker.  The sentence "Now I feel sick," dictates a certain kind of language logic from an English language perspective for the following sentence.

The ideas can best be expressed in English:

1) I feel sick now.  I wish I didn't eat pork with cheese for dinner so often.

1) I feel sick now.  I wish I hadn't eaten pork with cheese for dinner.

In my opinion you really need the phrase "so often." and number two is how most native English speakers would express this pork and cheese problem.  Number two cannot take "so often" because of the present perfect.